# Accurate computation of $\exp(a x^2) Q(x)$ for big values of $x$?

Tags: exponential-function, floating-point, error-function

I was wondering how one can accurately compute the value of $\exp(a x^2) Q(b x)$ for large values of

$$x \left(Q(x) \triangleq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^{\infty}  e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} du \right)?.$$

By Chernoff bound the value is upper-bounded by $\frac12 \exp((a - \frac{b^2}{2})x^2)$, hence whenver $a < \frac{b^2}{2}$ (which is the case I'm considering) the value must be close to zero (for large $x$). However, direct computation of the value (for example in a C code using the built-in functions of the standard math library) would evaluate to -nan values simply because we are multiplying a very big number by a very tiny one.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to rearrange the above to get precise results?

Answer (score 0):

See e.g. the [Cephes](http://www.moshier.net/#Cephes) library for the *Exponentially scaled erfc function* $\mathrm{erfce}(x) = \mathrm{erfc}(x)\exp x^2$ in the file ndtr.c. There is also an efficient asymptotic expansion for large x, i.e.
for $x > 128$ the function can be computed with the expression ($y = 1/(2x^2)$:
$$
\mathrm{erfce}(x) \sim \big(1 - y + 3 y^2 - 15 y^3 + 105 y^4 - 945 y^5 + O(y^6)\big)/(x\sqrt\pi)
$$

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find the mentioned function in ndtr.c. Could you please verify if it exists in the version that I download from http://www.moshier.net/#Cephes?

Comment: Interesting. It seems not to be in the main distribution files. Download http://www.moshier.net/double.zip

Comment: Indeed, I can find the mentioned file but there is no function called erfce there.

Comment: I just downloaded the http://www.moshier.net/double.zip and it is in the zip, the erfce code starts at line 489.

Comment: Thank you very much. Apparently http://www.moshier.net/cephes-math-28.tar.gz was different. I now see the code. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically, your integral  behaves as

> $$ e^{a x^2} (Q(x) \triangleq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^{\infty}  e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} du) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}(2a-1)x^2}} {x} .$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for some reasons the questions was not shown properly. In fact I am interested in $\exp(ax^2) Q(x)$.